# Positioning of Icons in 'Add a New Item' Dialogue

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

The positioning of the options in the 'Add a New Item' dialogue of Developer Story appears broken using Internet Explorer 11 (v11.0.9600.18449):

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your report, it has been fixed now. It'll be live after one of our next production builds.